# Run Ruby bundler gems as Xcode build scripts

Tags: ios, xcode, bundler

I use Bundler to manage gems in my iOS project.
I want to be able to run gems from bundle automatically during the build.
However, if I'm trying to use bundle in 'run script' build stage, Xcode cannot find command `bundle` (which is reasonable, since we're modifying `$PATH` in `.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few ways to modify OS X environment variables.
However, there's an easy workaround in this case.
In the 'run script' build stage:
`source ~/.bash_profile && bundle exec ...`.